# How to move past the autocompleted tag in Visual Studio Code with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2015, tags

[Look at the `</title>` tag in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEM4H.jpg)

Is there a way or any key combination to move past that `</title>` tag after I have written `My Home Page`, in Visual Studio Code? The `</title>` tag gets highlighted on its own too, so there must be something. I know the `end` key on keyboard will do the job, but if the closing tag is on the next line, it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a macro or this extension: [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) (which also moves to a location determined by a regular expression).

This into your settings.json:

```
"selectby.regexes": {

  "movePastTag": {
    "moveby": "</.*?>",
  }
}
```

And then a keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+\\",               // whatever keybinding you want 
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "command": "moveby.regex",
  "args": [
    "movePastTag",                    // go past the next ending tag
    "moveby",
    "next",
    "end"
  ],
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html"  // to restrict it to html files
},
```

Obviously, with badly formed html you can defeat the simple regex `</.*?>"` that I used.  Also with nested tags it will just jump to the next closing tag of any kind, not necessarily the matching end tag for the tag you are in.  But just hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and keep hitting <kbd>\</kbd> to get to where you want.

There is a command `Go To Bracket` that will go to the matching closing bracket even with nested tags but it goes to the beginning of the tag not the end as you waned.  There is also an emmet command that goes into the matching tag (but not past) and your cursor has to be in or next to the other tag for it to work (not in the textContent of the tag as in your example)..

Answer (score 0):

Does pressing tab accomplish what you’re looking for?